# How to manipulate values in a Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to manipulate data in a dataTable for a Gridview.

I have tried this:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string old = row["Udløb"].ToString();
            old = old.Remove(old.Length - 8);
            row["Udløb"] = old;
         }
```

**and** like this:

```
   for(int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                string old = dt.Rows[i]["Udløb"].ToString();
                old = old.Remove(old.Length - 8);
                dt.Rows[i]["Udløb"] = old;

            }
```

I have tried with and **without** `dt.AcceptChanges();`
But i always end up with the **old datatable** rendered in the gridview.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string old = row["Udløb"].ToString();
        old = old.Remove(old.Length - 8);
        row["Udløb"] = old;
    }
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you rebind the DataTable to the Grid?

Comment: you should bind datatable to datagridview : YourDataGridView.DataSource = dt; YourDataGridView.DataBind();